# too many values to unpack python, unsure why this does not work

Tags: python, tuples

Im using a tuple to store temperature and pressure data streamed in from an Arduino.

However, I am getting a

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack.
```

Here is my tuple

```
dataT = ([86.11, 86.11, 86.11], [715.91854, 715.91854, 715.91854])

for t, p in dataT:
    print "Temperature: ", t, "Pressure: ", p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your code, `for` iterates over 2-element tuple. It tries to unpack first element:

```
t, p = [86.11, 86.11, 86.11]
```

and this fails, since there are too many elements in the list.

You are probably trying to do following:

```
for t, p in zip(*dataT):    # or zip(dataT[0], dataT[1]):
    print "Temperature: ", t, "Pressure: ", p
```

Comment: Yes the zip(dataT[0], dataT[1]) worked perfectly.  Thanks a ton!